# Can I connect to an EC2 instance with one key-pair while forwarding another?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, fabric, ssh-keys

I need to connect to an EC2 instance with the Amazon-provided key-pair, but I would like to forward the public key associated with my Github account so that I can pull from my private repo (with Fabric). Is this possible? If so, do I need to have my public key on each remote machine I would like to pull from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use the -i option with ssh.  And the agent and agent forwarding with your github account.

```
ssh -i my_aws_key_pair.pem -A myawshost
```

I assume that from your question, you know how to do the whole agent thing.  By the way, you can add your aws key pair to your agent `ssh-add my_aws_key_pair.pem` and then you just need to do ssh -A.  That will forward both keys though.  Not sure if you wanted to avoid that or not.

Comment: I've tried this, and I'm seeing that private repos from Github cannot be pulled due to public key denial.

Comment: Do you see your github key whey you do `ssh-add -l`?  Are you using the proper username (git)?  Can you post the command you're trying, and the error message?  ssh -vvv provides a lot more info.